# What does "get wound" mean?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In the sixth panel of [this web comic](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20110817) the character says, "Get wound, Sturmvoraus*! I do not need your help."

So, what does "get wound" mean in this context? I googled it, but only got "getting wound up", which means "getting excited" or "getting worked up" to me, which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense here. How would you interpret it?

* "Sturmvoraus" is the name of the red-haired character. He is in a sort of personal rivalry/power struggle with the brown-haired character, but they are currently forced allies with common goals and trust each other to a degree because of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Get wound" is an insult, one that has essentially the same meaning as the more popular "get bent".

Urban Dictionary defines "[get bent](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20bent)" as:

> Much more subtle than fuck you or go to hell, but with all the impact. It is the abbreviated imperative for, "You should get bent over, so someone can sodomize you on Christmas!" Used in reply to outrageous requests...

In your example, the brown-haired character is telling Sturmvoraus to fuck off without using those exact words.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. Is "get wound" common usage, or is it somewhat outdated?

Comment: I would say that "get wound" is somewhat outdated, though these kinds of phrases are sometimes region-oriented so what could be commonplace in one place might be almost foreign a few hundred miles away. "Get Bent" is far more common to hear where I live (New York) than "get wound".

Comment: To my ear, it also ties in tangentially to the comic’s fondness for clockwork-powered contraptions — not by any specific literal interpretation, but just the vague word-association.

Answer (score 3):

"Get wound"  might be expanded as "go get wound around your own axle".   Consider it as an alternative to "pound sand".   The idea is that it would be preferable for the subject of the insult to go *do* something useless and unpleasant elswhere than for them to *be* useless and unpleasant here.